# Создание многостраничных сайтов на Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular, веб-сайт

Видел на https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS , что angular используется для создания одностраничных сайтов. А 2-х или более страничные возможно создавать c помощью angular и если да, то как?

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под многостраничными?

Answer (score 1):

Angular позволяет создавать SPA приложения (одностраничные). То есть существует только лишь index.html в который Angular загружает все модули и компоненты.

Чтобы сделать многостраничное приложение в Angular есть RouterModule, который позволяет реализовать маршрутизацию внутри приложения.